# Can logstash automatically identify KV pairs in the logs and parse them

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Can Logstash automatically identify KV pairs in the logs and parse them just like how splunk does.

I actually wrote one GROK filter which parses the fields and defined a KV filter so that the additional fields can be parsed out. But some logs are so random that they dont match my GROK and from those logs i have to parse the KV pairs into fields.

I wrote a GROK:

```
%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME},%{NUMBER:duration} %{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{WORD:Activity} \[\{%{DATA:foo1}\}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:foo2}
```

and in the logstash config file i will define the KV filter on fields foo1 and foo2.

Below are the log lines which i am expecting to be parsed into additional field:

```
[%t] 08 Aug 2017 18:55:38,179 INFO  ApiConsumer [{applicationSystemCode=monicapp-app, clientIP=10.x.x.x, clusterId=Cluster-Id-NA, containerId=Container-Id-NA, correlationId=205c2806-2f97-f42f-00f5-9a43aafb9eb3, domainName=defaultDomain, hostName=10.x.x.x.domain.com, messageId=10.202.100.34-4041d41d-75f3-4282-9aab-dd1ab17ecdf3, userId=ANONYMOUS, webAnalyticsCorrelationId=B347BC083EB9DCE4ED5005506F1F1E63|}]: Accept="applications/json; v=1.0" Api-key="272df4bd-cb92-467e-b20b-4059e235b68e" Client-Correlation-Id="205c2806-2f97-f42f-00f5-9a43aafb9eb3" Content-Type="application/json" URL="https://mus.domain.com/private/appm/details-search"


[%t] 08 Aug 2017 18:55:38,203 INFO  ApiConsumer [{applicationSystemCode=monicapp-app, clientIP=10.x.x.x, clusterId=Cluster-Id-NA, containerId=Container-Id-NA, correlationId=205c2806-2f97-f42f-00f5-9a43aafb9eb3, domainName=defaultDomain, hostName=ip-x-x-x.domain.com, messageId=10.x.x.34-4041d41d-75f3-4282-9aab-dd1ab17ecdf3, userId=ANONYMOUS, webAnalyticsCorrelationId=B347BC083EB9DCE4ED5005506F1F1E63|}]: KpiMetric="Cta" TransactionName="ApplicationDetail" TransactionStatus="Success" User="Associate(firstName=mike, lastName=daniel, role=Consultant, email=mike.daniel@domain.com, electronicId=mkd)"
```

The challenge here in the second log line where i would like to also parse the fields inside `User="Associate(firstName=mike, lastName=daniel, role=Consultant, email=mike.daniel@domain.com, electronicId=mkd)"`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do that this way:

1. Extract field that contains KV pairs using GROK. This will create a desired field
2. Use [KV filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) in order to split that field into pairs